# Can I safely disable a firewall rule added by Visual Studio Code?

Tags: firewall, visual-studio-code, windows-firewall

I am starting web development on Visual Studio Code, and I'm using Live Server to test the resulting pages on my browser. I want also to test using my mobile phone connected on the same private network. However my Windows 10 Firewall blocks my connection, even after adding an inbound rule to allow my mobile phone to send request to the Live Server.

I identified the exact rule that was blocking me. It's a (Profile=Private) rule added by Visual Studio Code that blocks all TCP connections to `code.exe`. Disabling this rule allows me to access Live Server from my mobile phone.

Would it be safe to disable it? Or is there a way to rewrite my Allow Inbound rule to override it for my specific use case?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Explicit "Block" rules in Windows Firewall always take priority over any kind of "Allow" rule.

The rule was not added by VSCode itself. Usually a "Block" rule gets added when you get the automatic Windows Firewall GUI prompt whether to allow or disallow inbound connections for an app, and when you *cancel* that prompt.

[image: Screenshot of the prompt in question]

So either manually change it to an "Allow" rule, or delete the rule completely to have Windows Firewall re-prompt you about the program the next time it tries to set up a listening socket.

Answer (score 2):

The Microsoft article
[Configure Windows Firewall for remote debugging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/configure-the-windows-firewall-for-remote-debugging?view=vs-2022)
gives precise instructions on what you need to do:

> 1. In Windows **Start** menu, search for and open **Windows Firewall with Advanced Security**. Starting in Windows 10, this is **Windows
>    Defender Firewall with Advanced Security**.
> 2. For a new incoming port, select **Inbound Rules** and then select New **strong text**Rule. For an outgoing rule, select **Outbound
>    Rules** instead.
> 3. In the **New Inbound Rule Wizard**, select **Port**, and then select **Next**.
> 4. Select either **TCP** or **UDP**, depending on the port number from the following tables.
> 5. Under **Specific local ports**, enter a port number from the following tables, and select **Next**.
> 6. Select **Allow the Connection**, and then select **Next**.
> 7. Select one or more network types to enable, including the network type for the remote connection, and then select **Next**.
> 8. Add a name for the rule (for example, msvsmon, IIS, or Web Deploy), and then select **Finish**.

You may further restrict the rule to `code.exe` and more.

The port to open is from the list port 4026, Incoming, TCP.
For more information, see Visual Studio remote debugger port assignments.

You may leave the Block rule enabled, as the new rule will take
precedence.

From Microsoft's article
[Best practices for configuring Windows Defender Firewall](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-firewall/best-practices-configuring) :

> 1. Explicitly defined allow rules will take precedence over the default block setting.
> 2. Explicit block rules will take precedence over any conflicting allow rules.
> 3. More specific rules will take precedence over less specific rules, except if there are explicit block rules as mentioned in 2. (For
>    example, if the parameters of rule 1 include an IP address range,
>    while the parameters of rule 2 include a single IP host address, rule
>    2 will take precedence.)

As the new Allow rule is more specific than the Block rule, it will
take precedence.